# SQL Server 2008 R2 can't connect to local database in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

I first installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Management Studio and then I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. I have the instance `SQLEXPRESS` running and it is set to automatic.

I am trying to connect to it locally using Windows authentication - server name is set to local and the username is grayed out and set to my profile username.

When I try to connect I get the following error:

[image]

Have I installed the wrong SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If your instance is called `SQLEXPRESS`, then you need to use `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or  `yourMachineName\SQLEXPRESS` as your server name - if you have a **named instance**, you need to specify that name of the instance in your server name.

Comment: I was losing faith at 2am until I came across your answer, thanks

Answer (score 63):

Your "[SQL Server Browser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087(v=sql.105).aspx)" service has to be started too.

Browse to Computer Management > Services.
[image: how to browse to computer management]

Find find "SQL Server Browser"

1. set it to Automatic
2. and also Manually start it (2)

[image: how to edit sql server browser properties and start it]

Hope it helps.

Comment: In my case, the SQL Server service itself (vs SQL Server Browser) was not started. Description of SQL Server service: "Provides storage, processing and controlled access of data, and rapid transaction processing". I needed to start it following @Kenan's instructions above, or else I can't "access of data"! Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Follow these steps to connect with SQL Server 2008 r2 (windows authentication)

**Step 1:**  Goto Control Panel --> Administrator Tools --> Services 
 select SQL SERVER (MSSQLSERVER) and double click on it

**Step 2:** 
Click on start Service

**Step 3:**
Now login to SQL server with Windows authentication 
and use user name : (local)

Enjoy ...

Answer (score 10):

I also received this error when the service stopped. Here's another path to start your service...

1. Search for "Services" in you start menu like so and click on it:

[image]

2. Find the service for the instance you need started and select it
   (shown below)
3. Click start (shown below)

[image]

Note: As Kenan stated, if your services *Startup Type* is not set to *Automatic*, then you probably want to double click on the service and set it to *Automatic*.

Answer (score 2):

I know, this problem can be faced by so many people and many of them have uninstalled and re-installed the sql server for resolving this issue. 
In my observation the problem of not connecting the database service locally is just because of your network connection you are using, in most of the cases these problems will come when you are using wi-fi network.

**Solution**  is, if you are using wi-fi then just right click on status of the network and get the ip details and enter the same ip in sql server name,
it will work.
Regards
Vishwajeet

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error but with different case. Let me quote the solution from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c5323e24-73f3-4c7d-9623-441f05db5d1e/sql-server-2008-cant-connect-to-local-named-instance?forum=sqlgetstarted):

> Luckly I also have the same set up on my desktop.  I have installed
>   first default instance and then Sql Express.  Everything is fine for
>   me for several days.  Then I tried connecting the way you trying, i.e
>   with MachineName\MsSqlServer to default instance and I got exctaly the
>   same error.
>
> So the solution is when you trying to connect to default instance you
>   don't need to provide instance name.(well this is something puzzled
>   me, why it is failing when we are giving instance name when it is a
>   default instance? Is it some bug, don't know)
>
> Just try with - PC-NAME and everything will be fine.  PC-NAME is the
>   MSSQLServer instance.
>
> Edit :  Well after reading your question again I realized that you are
>   not aware of the fact that MSSQLSERVER is the default instance of Sql
>   Server.  And for connecting to default instance (MSSQLSERVER) you
>   don't need to provide the instance name in connection string.  The 
>   "MachineName" is itself means "MachineName\MSSQLSERVER".

Answer (score 1):

Lots of the above helped for me, plus the accepted answer, but since I was on an EC2 instance, I had no idea what my instance name was. Finally, I opened SQLServer Configuration Manager and in the Name column, use whatever is there as your connection server, so in my case, .\EC2SQLEXPRESS and worked great!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there might be various reasons behind Sql Server Management Studio's(SSMS) above behaviour:

1.It seems that if our SSMS hasn't been opened for quite some while, the OS puts it to sleep.The solution is to manually activate our SQL server as shown below:

- Go to Computer Management-->Services and Applications-->Services. As you see that the status of this service is currently blank which means that it has stopped.
  [image]
- Double click the SQL Server option and a wizard box will popup as shown below.Set the startup type to "Automatic" and click on the start button which will start our SQL service.
  [image]
  [image]
- Now check the status of your SQL Server. It will display as "Running".
  [image]
- Also you need to check that other associated services which are also required by our SQL Server to fully function are also up and running such as SQL Server Browser,SQL Server Agent,etc.

2.The second reason could be due to incorrect credentials entered.So enter in the correct credentials.

3.If you happen to forget your credentials then follow the below steps:

- First what you could do is sign in using "Windows Authentication" instead of "SQL Server Authentication".This will work only if you are logged in as administrator.
- Second case what if you forget your local server name? No issues simply use "." instead of your server name and it should work.
  [image]

**NOTE:** This will only work for local server and not for remote server.To connect to a remote server you need to have an I.P. address of your remote server.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem. My solution is: change same password of other in windowns. Restart Service (check logon in tab Service SQL).

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't make any sense. "*same password*" - same as what? "*of the other*" - of the other what?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy - Same as the other "windowns," duh! ;)