# Connect with SQLServer Express 2012

Tags: remote-access

I am using SQLServer Express 2012 into our server but I am unable to connect the same from my local machine. Even I enabled all the service which we should enable before remotely access the SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: it should assist you to deal with your problem [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809196/sql-server-2008-r2-cant-connect-to-local-database-in-management-studio)

Comment: I did everything what I can. like Enabling TCP Prot, Browser Service but not able to connect with sql-server remotely.

Comment: **Solved**  apart from _TCP_ Port opening. I registered respective port within firewall also to enable communication.