# Fail to find mssqlserver (SQLEXPRESS) in SQL server configuration management

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

i have installed SQL server 2008 R2, but i fail to connect to local database,

so i went to SQL server configuration management to enable the SQLEXPRESS service, but fail to[image] find.Can anyone occur the same issue? and how to solve it? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yABU9.png)

[image]

Comment: is there any error message?  if you write, we can help

Comment: hi, i have added error message, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running the wrong version of SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Please check the first table of [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx) and try running, for example, SQLServerManager10.msc from Start > Run.

Also, if you run SQL Server Management Studio, try running as administrator (press shift and right-click the icon to see such option).

Comment: Have you tried to run the different versions of SQLServerManagerXX.msc ?

Comment: In the Task Manager, do you see MSSQLSERVER running?

Comment: Yes, i have tried different version of SQLServerManagerXX.msc

Comment: I didn't see MSSQLSERVER running in Task Manager

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly a settings problem. You need discovery switched on as well as the correct protocol types. In SQL Server Configuration Manager ensure that you have the same protocols enabled for all servers (use TCP/IP if it is a remote server).

Answer (score 0):

Look this link.  Its similar problem.

[SQL Server 2008 R2 can't connect to local database in Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809196/sql-server-2008-r2-cant-connect-to-local-database-in-management-studio)

Shortly,

Go to SQL Server Configuration Manager

Start->all program->SQL Server 2008 R2->Configuration Tools->SQL Server Configuration Manager

Explore "SQL Server Network Configuration" and then select "Protocols For MSSQLSERVER".

Check your TCP/IP Protocols in right side pane. If it is disabled then enabled it and Restart the "Sql Server(MSSQLSERVER) service" that available in "SQL Server 2008 R2 services pane".

You can follow the same steps to make sure for other protocols and services.

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i couldn't find Protocols for MSSQLSERVER in SQL Server Network Configuration

Comment: Thanks, but in my PC, it said: There is no items to show in this view , when i click 'SQL Server Network Configuration' in the right hand

Comment: I have attached the screen capture in the post.

Comment: it seems missing setup. I think re-install ms sql server.